# Why doesn't MySQL calculate the maximum varchar length in a column prior to creating a temp table including that columns values?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, query-optimization

Background:
For a long time I used varchar(255) for pretty much any string I knew would be under 255 char. I later learned the benefits of using varchar(20) or similar to better define my fields, and in some sense, even help sanitize input.
i.e. I know when storing the data, say the string "Hello World!" for example, varchar(20) and varchar(255) use the same storage space, but then if I were to reference that column in any query that creates a temp table for comparison/calculation, MySQL would use more RAM for the table (each value would be padded out to 255 character) but even in the case of varchar(20) and a column with "Hello World!"(12 char) and all other strings of 10 characters or less, MySQL is using more RAM than strictly necessary to keep the table in working memory.

Would it not use less memory to first calculate the max length of any value in the column?

***Pseudo Code***

```
var max = value1.length;
foreach(value){
     if(value.length > max)
     {max=value.length}
}
```

then use the max as the length of the column for the temp table?

I can't figure out why this wouldn't use less memory, at least concurrently. So maybe a better question is, why isn't it done this way? Is it too much of a performance trade off in terms of time/processor use for the calculation? Is there a practical possibility of performing this calculation before the memory for the temp table is allocated?

Strict Question:
Why doesn't MySQL calculate the maximum varchar length in a column prior to creating a temp table including that columns values?

EDITS:
To respond to some good comment questions/points:

Re: Larnu 7B value example -
It would certainly be expensive to check 7b values but if it’s a varchar(255) and the longest value is actually only 190 characters, then you’d be preventing the engine from creating 455b extra blank spaces in storage... so I guess I’m wondering why would the check before, certainly, be the worse of the two scenarios.

Re: Raymond Nijland. You don’t make any concrete point against the concept. You acknowledge that it uses more RAM, but don’t have any rational why that trade off is better or more efficient. Simply saying the varchar to char conversion is easier to work with is like saying it’s better to chop fire wood with an axe than a hydraulic press because it’s simpler. Extreme analogy I know, but logic is the same. So other than it might be hard to effectively code in an efficient manner, I’m trying to figure out, WHY would it be less efficient. Or if it could be more efficient

Re: Rick James stating it is implemented -
Led me to more specific searches and I now believe my question is superfluous as MySQL seems to have implemented this as feature in 8.0 onward. I’m hoping someone more familiar with the situation can confirm that for me though. Or provide the details in terms a developer would better understand > a DB Admin (hint I’m not the DB Admin)

Comment: mysql or sqlserver  ??

Comment: Regardless of RDBMS, why would you expect the data engine to check the length of every row first and then calculate the appropriate length? The reason the length parameter is there for a `varchar` is so that you, the developer, defines the object appropriately and lets the data engine know "this field will be up to 255 characters". With a small table, checking the length of 10 rows isn't that expensive, but imagine checking the length of 1,000,000,000 rows, which have 7  columns all defined as a `varchar(255)`. Do you *really* think it would be quick the check the length of 7B values? Hint: No

Comment: Also, your Pseudo Code is written in an iterative sense (a loop), that's literally the worse way for an RDBMS to check data. Data Engines excel at tasks with datasets, and are very poor at iterative tasks. This is by using a Loop or recursive CTE to create a list numbers performs poorly compared to something like a Tally Table.

Comment: *"Strict Question: Why doesn't MySQL calculate the maximum varchar length in a column prior to creating a temp table including that columns values?"* why would `var max = value1.length;
foreach(value){
     if(value.length > max)
     {max=value}
}` be faster then a simple `varchar(n)` to `char(n)` conversion which MySQL does.  Yes you will use up more RAM but Disk I/O also isn't cheap you know your code would require to view all table pages in worse case all from disk.

Comment: *"Strict Question: Why doesn't MySQL calculate the maximum varchar length in a column prior to creating a temp table including that columns values?"* Also fixed width datatypes in memory is much easier to work with

Comment: @scaisEdge I tagged sqlserver as well because while I'm not sure how it calculates the field, I assumed it handled it the same way.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the replies, I wasn't implying the pseudo code was the optimal way to handle it, just trying to provide a quick version of the logic to compare them. At least for me that's always easier than trying to work through a written explanation in English.

Comment: Questions about why one particular optimisation is not implemented is too broad and out of scope of SO. You should ask the developers.

Answer (score 1):

The solution decided upon for MySQL 8.0 is to implement `VARCHAR` instead of converting to `CHAR`.

Comment: So starting with MySQL 8.0 the engine actually is calculating the length instead?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/internal-temporary-tables.html My interpretation after reading this

Comment: @TCooper - Hmmm...  That page is a confusing mess of different cases.  I was going from a tidbit I got at a trade show; now I am wondering.

Comment: When in-memory internal temporary tables are managed by the TempTable storage engine, rows that include VARCHAR columns, VARBINARY columns, or other binary large object type columns (supported as of MySQL 8.0.13) are represented in memory by an array of cells, with each cell containing a NULL flag, the data length, and a data pointer. Column values are placed in consecutive order after the array, in a single region of memory, without padding. Each cell in the array uses 16 bytes of storage. <— this paragraph is what stood out to me

Comment: @TCooper - Yeah.  And the "16 bytes" stood out to me -- in many cases the representation of the row will be _bigger_ than the original.  And it won't even have any of the varchars/blobs/etc!  Looks like a fiasco.

Answer (score 1):

It does, but it probably still isn't the best option. Only in some cases. Realistically a lot of further optimization is needed.

Answer (score 0):

by the execution order, mysql first creates the structure of the temporary table, it is based on the profile of the SELECT query for the next query.